# When I try to start Hazelcast Managment Center, it fails to start

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to Hazelcast 3.2.4 Management Center to start up in TC Server 3.2.4 Tomcat 7.  But even though it seems to start without errors in the logs, I can't access the page:

In Tomcat.log I can see

```
Line 203004: INFO: Deploying web application archive /vc2cmmkb019231n/app/pm13/process-1.3-build317/instances/vm1/webapps/mancenter-3.2.4.war
Line 203016: INFO: notifyApplicationLifecycle(localhost|mancenter-3.2.4)[START]
Line 203018: WARNING: handleStartEvent(localhost|mancenter-3.2.4)[START] failed (ConnectException) to send ping: No current registered listener
Line 204206: INFO: notifyApplicationLifecycle(localhost|mancenter-3.2.4)[STOP]
```

that indicates that mancenter has started and stopped, but when I try to access the web page:

```
http://my-host-name:8080/mancenter-3.2.4/
```

it doesn't load up.

I am using the following hazelcast spring configuration:

```
<bean id="hcMonitorInstance" class="com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast" destroy-method="shutdown" factory-method="newHazelcastInstance">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.Config">
            <property name="instanceName" value="hcMonitorInstanceConfig"/>
            <property name="groupConfig">
                <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig">
                    <property name="name" value="${px-monitor-monitor.com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig.name}"/>
                    <property name="password" value="${px-monitor-monitor.com.com.hazelcast.config.GroupConfig.password}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="networkConfig">
                <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.NetworkConfig">
                    <property name="join" ref="join"/>
                    <property name="port" value="${px-monitor-monitor.hazelcastInstanceConfig.port}"/>
                    <property name="portAutoIncrement" value="true"/> <!--THIS is FALSE in CIWS-->
                    <property name="interfaces">
                        <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.InterfacesConfig">
                            <property name="interfaces">
                                <list>
                                    <value>*</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="managementCenterConfig">
                <bean class="com.hazelcast.config.ManagementCenterConfig">
                    <property name="enabled" value="${hz.management.center.enabled}"/>
                    <property name="url" value="${hz.management.center.url}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Any Ideas on why it won't start up?  I have also looked in Catalina.out for errors, but none show up.  I've also tried hitting `http://my-host:8080/mancenter/` but that doesn't work either.  I can see the web app expanded in tomcat webapps folder and it looks to be correct.

Comment: Hi Brent,

I'll get one of our ManagementCenter experts involved. He can help you out.

Comment: thanks.  I can get this to run on my local machine, but not on my dev linux boxes.  I've tried 3 now.  It's quite strange.

Comment: It was late at night.  I had an apache proxy on 8080, and tomcat on 12180,  I hadn't added the proxy rules for this webapp.  however, that being said, I can see the login screen, I type in admin/admin and it returns back to the login screen.  I see lots of NotSerializableExceptions in the log  [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.model.User].

Comment: looks like it's due to our app using memcached for the session management, and trying to persist spring security through there?  Perhaps that's what's going on.  Wonder if I can turn that off.

Comment: I have tried to remove spring security so that it doesn't get confused with my other apps that are also using spring security and memcached to share the session, but the application won't even start up without that.  Any ideas on configuring spring security out of the hazelcast monitor?

Comment: Hi Brent, Could you please share the tomcat logs of management center, and also the logs of your spring app would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Run `java -version`. If it is 1.8.0_91 then that's the culprit. Following is what you do

- point to an older version of java (1.6 or 1.7 are fine) executable to run the mancenter; something similar to `java -jar mancenter-3.6.2.war 8200 mancenter`; I ran it on port 8200 so as to not conflict with existing app running on 8080
- that should bring up the mancenter; create the admin user
- now you should be able to start your 'normal' java version (1.8.0_91 most likely)

It appears the problem occurs with java 1.8.0_91 when no user has been created. Let me know if this worked.